# Is it possible to read the Process stdout InputStream into an NIO ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, inputstream, nio, bytebuffer

Is it possible to use NIO to process the stdout from a Process? I have it working with java.io, but this is something of an exercise to learn a bit more about NIO and to explore the possibility of performance improvements.

Basically I want to stream a large volume of text from stdout into a buffer as fast as possible without blocking, and then process the contents of that buffer later. The trouble is, I can't seem to figure out the right voodoo to make it work with NIO. This is where I am right now:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( ... );
Process p = pb.start();
stdout = new StreamConsumer(p.getInputStream());
new Thread(stdout).start();
// other stuff omitted for brevity
```

The class StreamConsumer looks like this:

```
class StreamConsumer implements Runnable
{
  private InputStream is;

  public StreamConsumer(InputStream is)
  {
    this.is = is;
  }

  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      ReadableByteChannel source = Channels.newChannel(is);

      // Is it possible get a channel to a ByteBuffer 
      // or MappedByteBuffer here?
      WritableByteChannel destination = ??;
      ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(128 * 1024);

      while (source.read(buffer) != -1)
      {
        buffer.flip();
        while (buffer.hasRemaining())
        {
          destination.write(buffer);
        }
        buffer.clear();
      }

      source.close();
      destination.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to simply have all the standard input in a single byte buffer at once?  Do you know a maximum length of the input stream?

Comment: I'd like to read it into a buffer all at once yes, but the length is unknown; typically in the 10 MB range though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe it or not, I think the writable byte channel you want is

```
ByteArrayOutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(<some large number>);
WritableByteChannel destination = Channels.newChannel(ostream);
```

Then when done

```
ostream.toByteArray()
```

contains the bytes to process.  Or, if you want a byte buffer,

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(ostream.toByteArray())
```

I don't see here how you get the output outside the runnable, but I suspect your original code had that.  Otherwise you might want the `StreamConsumer` to be a `Callable<ByteBuffer>`.

Comment: Excellent suggestion to use Callable. I can't believe I forgot about that. This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

I have created an open source library that allows non-blocking I/O between java and your child processes.  The library provides an event-driven callback model.  It depends on the JNA library to use platform-specific native APIs, such as epoll on Linux, kqueue/kevent on MacOS X, or IO Completion Ports on Windows.

The project is called [NuProcess](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess) and can be found here:

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess

Answer (score 1):

> you might want the StreamConsumer to be a Callable.

Another non blocking option to try might be to use Guava's ListenableFuture giving you success and failure callbacks without interpreting errors of your own.